# All Sprints not showing up in Iteration drop down on TFS burn down chart

Tags: tfs

[Burn down Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Jlj6.gif) In the attached screenshot, the Iteration drop down of the Burn down chart in TFS not showing all available sprints. What can be possible reasons ?

Comment: Could it be the the Warehouse is not syncing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The report requires sprint work items to be created and assigned an iteration path, start date and end date.

- Check if you have added sprint work items with `start` and `end`
  dates.
- Check if you have added the iteration paths with `start` and `end`
  dates.

For the burndown report to be useful and accurate, your team must perform the following activities for tracking tasks: (See [Sprint Burndown (Scrum)](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/scrum/sprint-planning) for details.)

> 1. [Schedule sprints](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/scrum/define-sprints) for your team.
> 2. [Define tasks](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/scrum/sprint-planning), and assign them to an **Iteration** and to your team’s
>      **Area path**.
> 3. Specify and update the **Remaining Work** field for each task or subtask
>      as it is worked on.
> 4. Update the **State** of each task as it progresses from **To Do** to **Done**.

If there are no any problems for above settings, just trying [Manually process the TFS data warehouse and analysis services cube](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/report/admin/manually-process-data-warehouse-and-cube) to force sync the data. If that not work, also try to [Rebuild the data warehouse and cube](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/report/admin/rebuild-data-warehouse-and-cube.). Then check the report again.